# Logging CPU spikes

Tags: macos, mac, cpu

I'm curious to see if there's a way to log which applications cause a spike in CPU cycles. I'm trying to figure out exactly how much processing power I use and which apps cause the spikes. Is there a program or some scripting arguments that monitor the cpu usage, and can log the application with the highest amount of cycles being used when I hit a certain percentage? Thanks for your help.  Also, I'm running Snow leopard with a 2.4 GHz Core2Duo processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [iStats](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) product. It is a simple dashboard to see the real time info. 
Otherwise you can try setting up a cron job use the below command to grep the CPU utilization of the of the top process.

```
top -us5
```